# Something wrong with my styling in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, shortcode, 960.gs

I have just finished creating a shortcode for column grids and now it is working properly in wordpress but now my CSS is having some problem whenever i apply the shortcodes.

Here is the image of my problem

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/font_zps75ea6335.png

Here is the code in my functions.php

```
//Two Columns
function two_columns( $atts, $content = null ) {
return '<div id="responsive-image-container" class="two columns responsive-image-container"><div class="responsive-image">' . do_shortcode( $content ) . '</div></div>';
}
add_shortcode('grid_2', 'two_columns');
```

Basically when i apply it on post or pages it should go like this [grid_2] Dummy Text [/grid_2]. I'm not sure why my styling is not working on the first paragraph but the second and third has some styling.

Page.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="sixteen columns page-format">
       <h2 class="page-title"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
</div>

<div class="page-format">       
       <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I checked the view source and it seems it's missing an opening < p > tag on the first paragraph and the second paragraph is missing a < /p > tag

```
<div class="page-format">       
       <div id="responsive-image-container" class="sixteen columns responsive-image-container"><div class="responsive-image"><br />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ornare lacinia blandit. Nam sodales eu metus a viverra. Aenean ac suscipit odio. Nullam ac dignissim neque, sed fringilla felis! Etiam egestas tellus sed posuere ultricies</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ornare lacinia blandit. Nam sodales eu metus a viverra. Aenean ac suscipit odio. Nullam ac dignissim neque, sed fringilla felis! Etiam egestas tellus sed posuere ultricies<br />
</div></div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: I think you need to clarify this with HTML output from the browser and the wordpress shortcode usage that is creating the output - an image tells us nothing.

Comment: There i added the HTML from Page.php

Comment: Where is `shortcode` used, it supposed to be something like `[short_code]`.

Comment: [grid_2] IMAGE, Dummy Text[/grid_2]. This is how i used it. Wherein it will show an image and then a short text.